# Display the following vector as a linear combination of the base B.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> The base $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}[t]_{\leq 2}$ of the space of polynomials of degree less or equal $2$ is given.$$B=\{2t^2+4t+2,t+3,t^2+5t+3\}$$Display the following vector as a linear combination of the base $B$: $8t^2+2\quad \in\mathbb{R}[t]_{\leq 2}$

Do I need to find $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\in\mathbb{R}$ with $$\lambda_1(2t^2+4t+2)+\lambda_2(t+3)+\lambda_3(t^2+5t+3)=8t^2+2$$or Am I completely mistaken? Can you please give a hint on how to go on?

Comment: You are completely correct. Now open up the left side, make some order and compare coefficients of corresponding powers of $\;t\;$ ...and get those coefficients $\;\lambda_i\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you, I did it like paulinho suggested in his post (on my own) and now im trying to get solutions for $\lambda_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. To continue, just match the coefficients of the left and right side: $$(2\lambda_1 + \lambda_3) t^2 + (4\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + 5\lambda_3) t + (2\lambda_1 + 3 \lambda_2 + 3 \lambda_3) = 8t^2 + 0t + 2$$
You can pull three equations in three variables ($\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$) from this one expression. Can you do that?

Comment: Not quite. Match up the coefficients of the $t^2$, $t$, and constant terms. So the first equation would be $2 \lambda_1 + \lambda_3 = 8$

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes complete sense. I didn't even thought about what I'm doing sorry

Comment: $\begin{align} 2 \lambda_1 + \lambda_3 = 8\\ 4\lambda_1+5\lambda_3=0\\ 2\lambda_1+3\lambda_2+3\lambda_3=2\end{align}$

Comment: Now, I will put the coefficients into a matrix and solve it, right?

Comment: The solution is $\frac{20}{3}(2t^2+4t+2)+\frac{14}{9}(t+2)-\frac{16}{3}(t^2+5t+3)=8t^2+2$

Comment: Yes, that's your answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks!